# Can I use a USB WiFi dongle to connect to available nearby WiFi networks if I have an offline computer?

Tags: wireless-networking, dongle

I think I might be confused about dongles. I have an old desktop computer that cannot connect to WiFi, and I've recently disconnected my home Internet, so I want to use a USB WiFi receiver so I can use my phone as a hotspot and be able to access the Internet on my desktop through my phone's data connection.

Is this what a WiFi dongle allows my computer to do? Perceive and connect to WiFi networks?
Or is it something totally different that uses some independent data connection? (and if so, from where does it get its data?)

A secondary question:
If this is how dongles work, and my phone 4G data is pretty slow at about 100 Mbps, then this would effectively cap my DL speed so that even if I use a 1200Mbps dongle, it would still only transfer at the bottleneck speed?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes USB dongles are the same as wireless built into a PC, its just USB.

Comment: Ok thank you, is there a reason to get the sort with antennae over the ones that are just a chip? Does it actually affect reliability or is it just useless bulk?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this what a WiFi dongle allows my computer to do?

A 802.11 wireless adapter would indeed allow you to connect to your 4G mobile hotspot.

> If this is how dongles work, and my phone 4G data is pretty slow at
>   about 100 Mbps, then this would effectively cap my DL speed so that
>   even if I use a 1200Mbps dongle, it would still only transfer at the
>   bottleneck speed? Thanks!

Your download/upload speeds are determined by your service provider.  If you are connected to a 4G mobile hotspot then you are limited by your 4G service provider.
I should add that in order to connect to your phone, your service provider and your phone, must support that feature.

Comment: Ok thank you, I've been seeing a lot of price variation in dongles -- a couple bucks on eBay and Amazon up to about forty bucks for similar 150Mbps units -- should I avoid the cheap off-brand Chinese ones? Should I expect them to have a poor connection and cut out a lot, or is it just super-simple tech that can be mass produced cheaply but still reliably?

Answer (score 0):

I have one of these (HUAWEI) and speed is quite decent but not Wi-Fi speeds in most places. Still I can connect another computer with a standard wireless card to this 4G card in a pinch. See what your provider says about speeds.